# Byte array lengths with Deflater and Inflater

Tags: java, byte, arrays

#### How do we understand the defined length of the `byte array`?

For instance in this example we are defining here that the length of the byte array is 100.

#### What if the data that would have to be written to the `byte array` would be longer than `100 bytes`?

The same for the result variable here. I don't understand how these lengths work and how to choose a proper length of a byte array for the needs if you don't know how big your data will be?

```
try {
         // Encode a String into bytes
         String inputString = "blahblahblah";
         byte[] input = inputString.getBytes("UTF-8");

         // Compress the bytes
         **byte[] output = new byte[100];**
         Deflater compresser = new Deflater();
         compresser.setInput(input);
         compresser.finish();
         int compressedDataLength = compresser.deflate(output);
         compresser.end();

         // Decompress the bytes
         Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
         decompresser.setInput(output, 0, compressedDataLength);
         **byte[] result = new byte[100];**
         int resultLength = decompresser.inflate(result);
         decompresser.end();

         // Decode the bytes into a String
         String outputString = new String(result, 0, resultLength, "UTF-8");
     } catch(java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
         // handle
     } catch (java.util.zip.DataFormatException ex) {
         // handle
     }
```

And for this example, the byte array that is used here as input, is actually called a buffer, how do we understand it?

Answer (score 3):

Here, when you call `compresser.deflate(output)` you cannot know the size needed for `output` unless you know how this method works. But this is not a problem since `output` is **meant as a buffer**.

So you should call `deflate` multiple times and insert `output` in another object like an `OutputStream`, like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];   
while (!deflater.finished()) {  
  int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);
  outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);   
}
```

Same goes for inflating.

Comment: For complete example: https://dzone.com/articles/how-compress-and-uncompress

Answer (score 0):

By allocating 100 bytes to the byte array, JVM guarantees that a buffer large enough to hold 100 JVM defined bytes (i.e. 8 bits) is available to the caller. Any attempt to access the array with more than 100 bytes would result in exception e.g. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` in case you directly try to access the array by `array[101]`.

In case the code is written as your demo, the caller assumes the data length never exceeds 100.

Comment: How can I then make sure that the buffer is apropriate as in the example? How do I have a buffer large enough for the data? Also what if the data would be sent, it would probably just transfer all those 100 bytes resulting in the compression being useless then?

Comment: Java libraries either read only 1 byte/char from the underlying io device (as those in `java.io`) or you have the option to call `receive()` or any method alike and pass in a max number of bytes/chars to read from the channel (`java.nio`). So you can set up a buffer and reuse it. The method also returns the actual amount of bytes/chars read so you know you have read up all data.

Comment: For a proper cache size, consider a size that 

1. Doesn't break your JVM memory and
2. Can read and hold most of your "small" messages in 1 call.